# I get invalid type error when trying to call readPixels

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl

```
context.readPixels(0, 0, context.drawingBufferWidth, context.drawingBufferHeight, context.RGBA, context.FLOAT, pixels);
```

This is the code. I get this error in the console:
**WebGL: INVALID_ENUM: readPixels: invalid type**

But this works perfectly fine:

```
context.readPixels(0, 0, context.drawingBufferWidth, context.drawingBufferHeight, context.RGBA, context.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

Float or int is supposed to be supported, but only unsigned_byte works.
There's no resource online on how to correctly apply a type that seems to work.
Everything follows a different pattern.

Comment: How are you creating the TypedArray `pixels`?

Answer (score 3):

FLOAT is not guaranteed to be supported. The only format/type combination that is guaranteed to be supported is RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE. [See Spec, section 4.3.1](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf)

After that one other **implementation dependent** format/type combo might be supported depending on the type of thing you're reading. You can query that with

```
const altFormat = gl.getParameter(gl.IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_FORMAT);
const altType = gl.getParameter(gl.IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_TYPE);
```

```js
const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl');
showAltFormat('canvas');

const ext1 = gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float');
const ext2 = gl.getExtension('WEBGL_color_buffer_float');
if (ext1 && ext2) {
  const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
  const tex = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0,
                gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, null);
  gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);
  showAltFormat('float rgba fb');
}

function showAltFormat(msg) {
  const altFormat = gl.getParameter(gl.IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_FORMAT);
  const altType = gl.getParameter(gl.IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_TYPE);
  console.log(msg, 'readPixel alternate format/type combo', glEnumToString(gl, altFormat), glEnumToString(gl, altType));
}

function glEnumToString(gl, value) {
  const keys = [];
  for (const key in gl) {
    if (gl[key] === value) {
      keys.push(key);
    }
  }
  return keys.length ? keys.join(' | ') : `0x${value.toString(16)}`;
}
```

The code above makes a RGBA/FLOAT texture and attached it to a framebuffer then checks the alternate format/type combo to read it. On Chrome it gets RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE, on Firefox it gets RGBA/FLOAT. Both are valid responses since the alternate combo is **implementation dependent**.