# WebGL Reading pixels properly from offscreen canvas

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

I know there are a lot of resources on this, but none of them have worked for me.
Some are: [webgl readpixels is always returning 0,0,0,0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156971/webgl-readpixels-is-always-returning-0-0-0-0/44534528#44534528), 
and this one: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44869599/readpixels-from-webgl-canvas\](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44869599/readpixels-from-webgl-canvas%5C)
as well as this one: [Read pixels from a WebGL texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626606/read-pixels-from-a-webgl-texture) 
but none of them have been either helpful or successful.

**The goal:** Render an offscreen canvas with a WebGL shader, then use that as a texture in a separate WebGL shader.

**Notes:**

- For these WebGL shaders, I'm using a generic vertex shader used for pixel shaders, specifically, a raytracer/raymarcher. This is: `attribute vec2 a_position; void main() { gl_Position = vec4(a_position.xy, 0.0, 1.0); }`. This vertex shader is inputted two triangles that cover the screen, so basically the fragment shader is doing all the work.

**Problem:** In order to get the image data off of the offscreen canvas, I've tried these methods:

1. The WebGL `gl.readPixels` function

```
var capturedImageData = new Float32Array(screenWidth * screenHeight * 4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, capturedImageData);
```

2. Using another canvas with `getContext('2d')`

```
var offscreenCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
offscreenCanvas.width = screenWidth;
offscreenCanvas.height = screenHeight;
var ctx = offscreenCanvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(glCanvas, 0, 0);
var capturedImageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
```

Both of these methods result in the `capturedImageData` array being filled with 
`0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, . . .` , which is obviously not right.

If anybody has experience with this problem, help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

A direct link to the program is:
https://www.khanacademy.org/cs/-/6289631977619456

Comment: Did you check the JavaScript console? You should have gotten an error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to *clarify* it, but not to include an answer within it. You should create your own answer (if one doesn't exist) with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, and then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to doing so). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the help! I'll do that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always look in the JavaScript console of your browser (press F12) or pick it from the menus. I should have shown an error for your code

```
var capturedImageData = new Float32Array(screenWidth * screenHeight * 4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, capturedImageData);
```

```js
const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl');
const screenWidth = 300;
const screenHeight = 150;
var capturedImageData = new Float32Array(screenWidth * screenHeight * 4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, capturedImageData);
```

When I run your code I get this error

```
js:16 WebGL: INVALID_ENUM: readPixels: invalid type
```

You can't read with `FLOAT`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61984296/i-get-invalid-type-error-when-trying-to-call-readpixels)

But, what you're trying to do, render to one texture and use that as input to another shader should not be done with readPixels. It should be done with framebuffers allowing you to directly render to a texture.

See [this](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-render-to-texture.html) or maybe one of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=Relevance&q=%5bwebgl%5d%20gl.bindFramebuffer)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've been reading about framebuffers and they do seem like a much better solution.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason gl.readPixels works better with a Uint8Array.

```
var capturedImageData = new Uint8Array(screenWidth * screenHeight * 4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, capturedImageData);
```

Here is a demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <canvas></canvas>
  <body>
    <script>
      var gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");    

    
     gl.clearColor(1, 0, 1, 1);
     gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    
    
      var pixels = new Uint8Array(4 * window.innerWidth * window.innerHeight);
      gl.readPixels(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
      
      
      console.log(pixels[0]);
    

  
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did end up solving the problem a few hours after I posted, and this was exactly the solution. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: No problem! I'll watch for the finished version :)